# C++ terminal handle keypress running in screen

Tags: c++, linux, console, gnu-screen

I need read keypress on the terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main()
{
    struct termios old_tio, new_tio;
    unsigned char c;

    /* get the terminal settings for stdin */
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO,&old_tio);

    /* we want to keep the old setting to restore them a the end */
    new_tio=old_tio;

    /* disable canonical mode (buffered i/o) and local echo */
    new_tio.c_lflag &=(~ICANON & ~ECHO);

    /* set the new settings immediately */
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&new_tio);

    do {
     c=getchar();
     printf("%d ",c);
    } while(c!='q');

    /* restore the former settings */
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&old_tio);

    return 0;
}
```

Make with command `gcc test.cpp -o test`

It is work correctly, but if I run this code on screen: `screen -dmS m ./test` I see in the terminal after reattach screen:

```
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
```

And my cpu load at 100%.
How I can fix this a problem?

Comment: For that kind of interactive program, I use NCurses.